# The ratio of the area of $\triangle ABC$ to the length of $EF$?

Tags: geometry, triangles

In $\triangle ABC$, D is the foot of perpendicular from A on BC. If E and F are the feet of perpendiculars from D on AB and AC respectively, find the ratio of the area of $\triangle ABC$ to the length of EF.

Comment: Have you tried drawing it? What did you notice?

Comment: I tried using some properties of a cyclic quadrilateral. But, I didn't get the answer.

Comment: area and length have different dimensions. how do you find the ratio?

Comment: The answer is in terms of R, where R is the circumradius. This explains it.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to see that:

- $DE=h\cos B$
- $DF=h\cos C$
- $\angle EDF= \pi - \angle A$
- $\angle DEF= \frac{\pi}2 - \angle C$  $\text{     } $ (as $ADEF$ is cyclic)

Where $h=AD$. Hence by the sine rule:

$$EF=\frac{DF\sin A}{\cos C}=h\sin A=\frac{ah}{2R}=\frac{\Delta}{R}$$